# express-validator - req.checkBody is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, express-validator

I've been trying to fix this for 2 hours now and I'm getting a little frustrated. Basicly, I want to validate a form input, but I always get this error.

```
TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function
at C:\Users\bobbo\Desktop\Develops\Project_folder\routes\index.js:19:7
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\bobbo\Desktop\Develops\Project_folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\bobbo\Desktop\Develops\Project_folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\bobbo\Desktop\Develops\Project_folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\bobbo\Desktop\Develops\Project_folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\bobbo\Desktop\Develops\Project_folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\bobbo\Desktop\Develops\Project_folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\bobbo\Desktop\Develops\Project_folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (C:\Users\bobbo\Desktop\Develops\Project_folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
at router (C:\Users\bobbo\Desktop\Develops\Project_folder\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

Pretty much the only info I could find is telling me to write the `app.use(expressValidator());`
after `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`, but it doesn't matter what I do, I still get the same error. Here is the code I use.

```
//index.js    
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();
    var expressValidator = require('express-validator');

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(expressValidator());
    var router = express.Router();
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    });

    router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('signup', { title: 'Express' });
    });

    router.post('/signup', function(req, res){
      var name = req.body.name;
      console.log(name);    //works
      req.checkBody("name", "Invalid name").notEmpty();
      var errors = req.validationErrors();
      if(errors){
        console.log('errors');
      } else{
        console.log('no errors');
      }
    });
    module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
//app.js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

package.json

```
    //package.json
{
  "name": "pizzaonline",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^5.2.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11"
  }
```

}

If I comment out `req.checkBody("name", "Invalid name").notEmpty();`, the next express-validation code to be executed is `var errors = req.validationErrors();`, giving me an identical error telling me `req.validationErrors()` is not a function. I'm new to this but this tells me that express-validator is not properly installed, am I wrong? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `express-validator` add those functions onto every `Request` object?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I followed a guide telling me to do this, and it seems to work for everyone except me. How do I know if the functions are added to every request object?

Comment: Log `Object.entries(req)` and see if it has the proper members that you're trying to access (requires ES2017)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It doesn't seem to contain those functions, no. How do I add them? Here are the results if you want to look at them: https://pastebin.com/Ejjphd51

Comment: @num8er I did what you said but nothing changed. Also tried with ´3.0.0´

Comment: @gorbut found Your problem and wrote an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your nested route files (`index.js` and `users.js`) You're creating new app instance and attaching that validator to it that in fact is not correct.

Cause by creating new app instance You create new app context that is different from `app` in `app.js`.

So here's the fix:

1) attach express validator above this lines in `app.js` file:

```
app.use(expressValidator());


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
```

2) remove `app` object generation from nested route files and make it look like:

```
//index.js    
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('signup', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/signup', function(req, res){
  var name = req.body.name;

  req.checkBody("name", "Invalid name").notEmpty();
  var errors = req.validationErrors();
  if(errors){
    console.log('errors');
  } else{
    console.log('no errors');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
npm i --save express-validator@4

reqiure app.js

app.use(expressValidator());
```

and try again

```
npm start
```